# Use ng-show on a custom replace directive does not show or hide

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show, ng-hide

I am having an issue with getting ng-show (or ng-hide) to work on a custom directive. It is working just fine on normal HTML elements.

I made up a very simple example that shows the issue:

```
<div ng-app="appMod">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl3">
      <button>First</button>
      <button ng-hide="NoSecond">Second</button>

      <mybutton ng-hide="NoSecond" label="My button"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
function Ctrl3($scope) {
    $scope.NoSecond = true;
};

var appmod = angular.module('appMod', []);

appmod.directive("mybutton", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<div style='border: 1px solid black;'><button>{{label}}</button></div>",
        scope: {label:'@'}
    };
});
```

The end result is that the  html button 'Second' is hidden, but 'mybutton' is not.
http://jsfiddle.net/fotoguy42/4j7td/2/

How can I make the ng-hide/show work on my widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so this is actually mostly a duplicate of [Why ng-hide doesn't work with custom directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850804/why-ng-hide-doesnt-work-with-custom-directives)

Because you're creating a new scope in your directive you have to pass the variable noSecond to the directive and include it in the new scope.

Also - you should really use camelCase for your javascript:

JS:

```
function Ctrl3($scope) {
  $scope.noSecond = true;
};

var appmod = angular.module('appMod', []);

appmod.directive("mybutton", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<div style='border: 1px solid black;'><button>{{label}}</button></div>",
        scope: {label:'@', noSecond: '='}
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="appMod">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl3">
      <button>First</button>
      <button ng-hide="noSecond">Second</button>

      <mybutton ng-hide="noSecond" label="My button" no-second="noSecond"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

It does appear that this has changed in angular 1.2.1 although I can't seem to find the change in the migration guide that would be responsible for this....

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Comment: Resolved in 1.2.0, probably with [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3fe4491a6bf57ddeb312b8a30cf1706f6f1d2355).

Comment: Man I dug around a lot (hours) and did not find that SO question.

Comment: eh - at least you have a pretty comprehensive idea now. I would probably just go with the angular upgrade as long as you're not worried about breaking anything else. It seems to me like the expected behavior would be the one you've described.

Comment: I did retest in fiddler, updating to 1.2.1 and it does now behave as expected.