# Showing or hiding the parent element of a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a query concerning a custom directive example found within Angular's docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate).

When the `select` method is called (from the parent controller in order to show / hide a pane), the relevant `<div class="tab-pane" ng-show="selected">` element is shown / hidden, which is how it should function as per the example, naturally.

However, I'd like to hide the parent element, which is `<my-pane title="...">` so that `<my-pane title="...">` isn't left visible (even though all it's child content is hidden.) In other words, move the `ng-show` directive from `<div class="tab-pane" ng-show="selected">` to `<my-pane title="..." ng-show="selected">`

I assumed that each `<my-pane title="...">` had its own isolated scope with a unique `$scope.id`, so it should be easy to accomplish by targetting the relevant scope and updating a `selected` value via the tab links, but for the life of me I cannot seem to make it work.

After inspecting both `<my-pane title="...">`'s in console it appears as they both have the same `$scope.id`, which shouldn't be the case as they're separate scopes, right?

Something is missing from my understanding of isolated scopes perhaps. Any pointers would be great.

Comment: From the link: The myPane directive has a require option with value ^^myTabs. 

When a directive uses this option, $compile will throw an error unless the specified controller is found. The ^^ prefix means that this directive searches for the controller on its parents. (A ^ prefix would make the directive look for the controller on its own element or its parents; without any prefix, the directive would look on its own element only.) 

>>>mypane looks for a controller in its parent mytabs.  mypane is not a parent for anything here.  I think you are confusing basic concepts.

Comment: @mahesh Thanks for the response. Yes, `myPane` is using `myTabs` as its controller due to the `require` definition, but even so I would have thought that each `myPane` created would have been assigned its own isolated scope with a unique ID due to the `scope` definition? In which case, it should be possible to move the `ng-hide` directive from `<div class="tab-pane">` to `<my-pane>` then show / hide that element instead.

Comment: As you can see from these SO threads:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396103/use-ng-show-on-a-custom-replace-directive-does-not-show-or-hide
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850804/why-ng-hide-doesnt-work-with-custom-directives
and this jsfiddle:  
http://jsfiddle.net/h7xvA/

It is possible if you pass that variable as a reference from the controller to the directive as in the fiddle above.